# Declare TikZ Style (JUST ONCE!)

Tags: tikzset

[In this link](https://%5CPassOptionsToPackage%7Bsvgnames,%20x11names%7D%7Bxcolor%7D%20%5Cdocumentclass%7Barticle%7D%20%5Cusepackage%5Ba4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm%5D%7Bgeometry%7D%20%5Cusepackage%5BT1%5D%7Bfontenc%7D%20%5Cusepackage%7Bmathtools%7D%20%5Cusepackage%7Bstix%7D%20%5Cusepackage%7Btikz%7D%20%5Cusetikzlibrary%7Bdecorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings%7D%20%5Cusepackage%5Bbb=ams%5D%7Bmathalpha%7D%20%5Cusepackage%7Bextarrows%7D%20%20%5Cnewcommand%7B%5CTonde%7D%5B1%5D%7B%5Cleft(#1%5Cright)%7D%20%20%5Cnewcommand%7B%5Ctonde%7D%5B1%5D%7B%5Cbigl(#1%5Cbigr)%7D%20%20%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%20%20%5Cbegin%7Bcenter%7D%20%5Cbegin%7Btikzpicture%7D%5Bscale=0.75%5D%20%5Cbegin%7Bscope%7D%20%5Cdraw%5Bred,%20thick%5D%20(0,0)%20--%20(1,1.73);%20%5Cdraw%5Bblue,%20thick%5D%20(1,1.73)%20--%20(2,0);%20%5Cdraw%5BGold1,%20thick%5D%20(0,0)%20--%20(2,0);%20%5Cdraw%5Blatex-latex,%20shorten%20%3E=3pt,red%5D%20(.4,.87)%20--%20(-1.5,2.02);%20%5Cdraw%5Blatex-latex,%20shorten%20%3E=3pt,blue%5D%20(1.6,.87)%20--%20(3.5,2.02);%20%5Cdraw%5Blatex-latex,%20shorten%20%3E=3pt,Gold1%5D%20(1,-.15)%20--%20(1,-2.15);%20%5Cend%7Bscope%7D%20%20%25%5Cpath%5Bsave%20path=%5CpathT%5D%20%5Cdraw%5Bred,%20thick%5D%20(-2,1.15)%20--%20(-1,2.89);%20%5Cdraw%5Bblue,%20thick%5D%20(-2,1.15)%20--%20(-3,2.89);%20%5Cdraw%5BGold1,%20thick%5D%20(-3,2.89)%20--%20(-1,2.89);%20%20%5Cbegin%7Bscope%7D%5Bxshift=6cm%5D%20%5Cdraw%5Bred,%20thick%5D%20(-2,1.15)%20--%20(-1,2.89);%20%5Cdraw%5Bblue,%20thick%5D%20(-2,1.15)%20--%20(-3,2.89);%20%5Cdraw%5BGold1,%20thick%5D%20(-3,2.89)%20--%20(-1,2.89);%20%5Cend%7Bscope%7D%20%20%5Cbegin%7Bscope%7D%5Bxshift=3cm,%20yshift=-5cm%5D%20%5Cdraw%5Bred,%20thick%5D%20(-2,1.15)%20--%20(-1,2.89);%20%5Cdraw%5Bblue,%20thick%5D%20(-2,1.15)%20--%20(-3,2.89);%20%5Cdraw%5BGold1,%20thick%5D%20(-3,2.89)%20--%20(-1,2.89);%20%5Cend%7Bscope%7D%20%20%5Cnode%5Bfont=%5CHuge%5D%20at%20(6,0.5)%20%7B$%5Ccong$%7D;%20%20%5Cbegin%7Bscope%7D%5Bxshift=8cm%5D%20%5Cdraw%5Bred,%20thick%5D%20(0,0)%20--%20(1,1.73);%20%5Cdraw%5Bblue,%20thick%5D%20(1,1.73)%20--%20(2,0);%20%5Cdraw%5BGold1,%20thick%5D%20(0,0)%20--%20(2,0);%20%5Cdraw%5Bred,dashed%5D%20(0,0)%20--%20(2.27,1);%20%5Cdraw%5Bblue%5D%20(2,0)%20--%20(2.27,1);%20%5Cdraw%5BGold1%5D%20(1,1.73)%20--%20(2.27,1);%20%5Cend%7Bscope%7D%20%20%25%5Cdraw%5Buse%20path=%5CpathT%5D;%20%20%5Cend%7Btikzpicture%7D%20%5Cend%7Bcenter%7D%20%20%5Cbegin%7Bcenter%7D%20%5Cbegin%7Btikzpicture%7D%20%5Cbegin%7Bscope%7D%5Bvery%20thick,decoration=%7B%20%20%20%20%20markings,%20%20%20%20%20mark=at%20position%200.625%20with%20%7B%5Carrow%7B%3E%7D%7D%7D%20%20%20%20%20%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cdraw%5Bpostaction=%7Bdecorate%7D%5D%20(0,0)--(1,0);%20%20%20%20%20%5Cdraw%5Bpostaction=%7Bdecorate%7D%5D%20(1,0)--(1,1);%20%20%20%20%20%5Cdraw%5Bpostaction=%7Bdecorate%7D%5D%20(1,1)--(0,1);%20%20%20%20%20%5Cdraw%5Bpostaction=%7Bdecorate%7D%5D%20(0,1)--(0,0);%20%5Cend%7Bscope%7D%20%5Cend%7Btikzpicture%7D%20%5Cend%7Bcenter%7D%20%20%5Cbegin%7Bcenter%7D%20%5Cbegin%7Btikzpicture%7D%20%5Ctikzset%7B%20%20%20%25%20style%20to%20apply%20some%20styles%20to%20each%20segment%20of%20a%20path%20%20%20on%20each%20segment/.style=%7B%20%20%20%20%20decorate,%20%20%20%20%20decoration=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20show%20path%20construction,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveto%20code=%7B%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lineto%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20--%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20curveto%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20..%20controls%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentsupporta)%20and%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentsupportb)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20..%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20closepath%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20--%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%25%20style%20to%20add%20an%20arrow%20in%20the%20middle%20of%20a%20path%20%20%20mid%20arrow/.style=%7Bpostaction=%7Bdecorate,decoration=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20markings,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mark=at%20position%20.5%20with%20%7B%5Carrow%5B#1%5D%7Bstealth%7D%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%7D,%20%7D%20%5Cpath%20%5Bdraw=blue,postaction=%7Bon%20each%20segment=%7Bmid%20arrow=red%7D%7D%5D%20(.2,0)%20--%20(3,1)%20arc%20(0:180:1.4%20and%201)%20--%20cycle%20(4,1)%20circle(.8)%20(6,1)%20ellipse(.5%20and%201)%20(0,3)%20to%20%5Bbend%20left%5D%20(3,4)%20(4,3)%20rectangle%20(6,4);%20%5Cend%7Btikzpicture%7D%20%5Cend%7Bcenter%7D%20%20%5Cbegin%7Bcenter%7D%20%5Cbegin%7Btikzpicture%7D%20%5Ctikzset%7B%20%20%20%25%20style%20to%20apply%20some%20styles%20to%20each%20segment%20of%20a%20path%20%20%20on%20each%20segment/.style=%7B%20%20%20%20%20decorate,%20%20%20%20%20decoration=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20show%20path%20construction,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveto%20code=%7B%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lineto%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20--%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20curveto%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20..%20controls%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentsupporta)%20and%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentsupportb)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20..%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20closepath%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20--%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%25%20style%20to%20add%20an%20arrow%20in%20the%20middle%20of%20a%20path%20%20%20mid%20arrow/.style=%7Bpostaction=%7Bdecorate,decoration=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20markings,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mark=at%20position%20.5%20with%20%7B%5Carrow%5B#1%5D%7Bstealth%7D%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%7D,%20%7D%20%5Cpath%20%5Bdraw=blue,postaction=%7Bon%20each%20segment=%7Bmid%20arrow=red%7D%7D%5D%20(0,0)%20rectangle%20(2,2)%20(0,2)%20--%20(2,0)%20(7,0)%20--%20(7,2)%20--%20(9,0)%20--%20(7,0)%20(8,2)%20--%20(10,2)%20--%20(10,0)%20(8,2)%20--%20(10,0);%20%5Cnode%20at%20(-.25,1)%20%7B%5C(a%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(2.25,1)%20%7B%5C(a%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(1,2.25)%20%7B%5C(u%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(1,-.25)%20%7B%5C(v%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(-1.5,1)%20%7B%5CHuge%7B%5C(P_%7Bw%27%7D=%5C)%7D%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(4.5,1)%20%7B%5Chuge%7B%5C(%5CxRightarrow%5B%5Ctext%7Bla%20diagonale%7D%5D%7B%5Ctext%7Btagliando%20lungo%7D%7D%5C)%7D%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(6.75,1)%20%7B%5C(a%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(10.25,1)%20%7B%5C(a%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(9,2.25)%20%7B%5C(u%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(8,-.25)%20%7B%5C(v%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(8,1.35)%20%7B%5C(b%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(9,0.65)%20%7B%5C(b%5C)%7D;%20%5Cend%7Btikzpicture%7D%20%5Cend%7Bcenter%7D%20%20%5Cbegin%7Bcenter%7D%20%5Cbegin%7Btikzpicture%7D%20%5Ctikzset%7B%20%20%20%25%20style%20to%20apply%20some%20styles%20to%20each%20segment%20of%20a%20path%20%20%20on%20each%20segment/.style=%7B%20%20%20%20%20decorate,%20%20%20%20%20decoration=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20show%20path%20construction,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveto%20code=%7B%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lineto%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20--%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20curveto%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20..%20controls%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentsupporta)%20and%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentsupportb)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20..%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20closepath%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20--%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%25%20style%20to%20add%20an%20arrow%20in%20the%20middle%20of%20a%20path%20%20%20mid%20arrow/.style=%7Bpostaction=%7Bdecorate,decoration=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20markings,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mark=at%20position%20.5%20with%20%7B%5Carrow%5B#1%5D%7Bstealth%7D%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%7D,%20%7D%20%5Cpath%20%5Bdraw=blue,postaction=%7Bon%20each%20segment=%7Bmid%20arrow=red%7D%7D%5D%20(0,0)%20circle%20(1cm)%20(4.5,-1)%20--%20(4.5,1)%20--%20(2.5,1)%20(4.5,-1)%20--%20(2.5,-1)%20--%20(2.5,1)%20(6,0)%20--%20(7,1)%20--%20(8,1)%20--%20(9,0)%20(6,0)%20--%20(7,-1)%20--%20(8,-1)%20--%20(9,0);%20%5Cnode%20at%20(0,1.25)%20%7B%5C(a%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(0,-1.25)%20%7B%5C(a%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(6.5,.75)%20%7B%5C(a%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(7.5,1.25)%20%7B%5C(a%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(2.25,0)%20%7B%5C(b%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(3.5,1.25)%20%7B%5C(c%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(4.75,0)%20%7B%5C(b%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(3.5,-1.25)%20%7B%5C(c%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(8.5,.75)%20%7B%5C(b%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(8.5,-.75)%20%7B%5C(c%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(7.5,-1.25)%20%7B%5C(b%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(6.5,-.75)%20%7B%5C(c%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(0,-2)%20%7B%5C(a%5E+a%5E+%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(3.5,-2)%20%7B%5C(b%5E+c%5E-b%5E-c%5E+%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(7.5,-2)%20%7B%5C(a%5E+a%5E+b%5E+c%5E+b%5E-c%5E-%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(1.5,0)%20%7B%5Chuge%7B%5C#%7D%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(5.5,0)%20%7B%5Chuge%7B$%5Ccong$%7D%7D;%20%5Cdraw%5Bdashed,%20-latex,%20shorten%20%3E=%203pt%5D%20(7,1)%20--%20(7.75,-.5);%20%5Cdraw%5Bdashed%5D%20(7,1)%20--%20(8,-1);%20%5Cend%7Btikzpicture%7D%20%5Cend%7Bcenter%7D%20%20%5Cbegin%7Bcenter%7D%20%5Cbegin%7Btikzpicture%7D%20%5Ctikzset%7B%20%20%20%25%20style%20to%20apply%20some%20styles%20to%20each%20segment%20of%20a%20path%20%20%20on%20each%20segment/.style=%7B%20%20%20%20%20decorate,%20%20%20%20%20decoration=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20show%20path%20construction,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20moveto%20code=%7B%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lineto%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20--%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20curveto%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20..%20controls%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentsupporta)%20and%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentsupportb)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20..%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20closepath%20code=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cpath%20%5B#1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentfirst)%20--%20(%5Ctikzinputsegmentlast);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%25%20style%20to%20add%20an%20arrow%20in%20the%20middle%20of%20a%20path%20%20%20mid%20arrow/.style=%7Bpostaction=%7Bdecorate,decoration=%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20markings,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mark=at%20position%20.5%20with%20%7B%5Carrow%5B#1%5D%7Bstealth%7D%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%7D,%20%7D%20%5Cpath%20%5Bdraw=blue,postaction=%7Bon%20each%20segment=%7Bmid%20arrow=red%7D%7D%5D%20(1,-1)%20--%20(0,0)%20--%20(1,1)%20--%20(2,1)%20--%20(3,0)%20--%20(2,-1)%20--%20(1,-1)%20(5,-1)%20--%20(4,0)%20--%20(5,1)%20--%20(6,1)%20--%20(7,0)%20--%20(6,-1)%20--%20(5,-1);%20%5Cnode%20at%20(1.5,-1.25)%20%7B%5C(b%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(0.375,-0.625)%20%7B%5C(c%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(0.375,.625)%20%7B%5C(d%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(1.5,1.25)%20%7B%5C(c%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(2.675,0.625)%20%7B%5C(b%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(2.675,-.625)%20%7B%5C(d%5C)%7D;%20%20%5Cnode%20at%20(5.5,-1.25)%20%7B%5C(e%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(4.375,-0.625)%20%7B%5C(e%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(4.375,.625)%20%7B%5C(f%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(5.5,1.25)%20%7B%5C(f%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(6.675,0.625)%20%7B%5C(g%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(6.675,-.625)%20%7B%5C(g%5C)%7D;%20%5Cnode%20at%20(3.5,0)%20%7B%5Chuge%7B$%5Ccong$%7D%7D;%20%5Cend%7Btikzpicture%7D%20%5Cend%7Bcenter%7D%20%20%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D) I found a very beautiful `\tikzset`. In a book that I'm writing I use several times this **tikzset**. Does exist a way to create a `\begin...\end{tikzpicture}` with this tikzset? For example I have this (long) code.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames, x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  % style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
  on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
      }}},
}
\path [draw=blue,postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=red}}]
(.2,0) -- (3,1) arc (0:180:1.4 and 1) -- cycle
(4,1) circle(.8)
(6,1) ellipse(.5 and 1)
(0,3) to [bend left] (3,4)
(4,3) rectangle (6,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  % style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
  on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
      }}},
}
\path [draw=blue,postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=red}}]
(0,0) rectangle (2,2) (0,2) -- (2,0) (7,0) -- (7,2) -- (9,0) -- (7,0) (8,2) -- (10,2) -- (10,0) (8,2) -- (10,0);
\node at (-.25,1) {\(a\)};
\node at (2.25,1) {\(a\)};
\node at (1,2.25) {\(u\)};
\node at (1,-.25) {\(v\)};
\node at (-1.5,1) {\Huge{\(P_{w'}=\)}};
\node at (4.5,1) {\huge{\(\xRightarrow[\text{la diagonale}]{\text{tagliando lungo}}\)}};
\node at (6.75,1) {\(a\)};
\node at (10.25,1) {\(a\)};
\node at (9,2.25) {\(u\)};
\node at (8,-.25) {\(v\)};
\node at (8,1.35) {\(b\)};
\node at (9,0.65) {\(b\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  % style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
  on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
      }}},
}
\path [draw=blue,postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=red}}]
(0,0) circle (1cm) (4.5,-1) -- (4.5,1) -- (2.5,1) (4.5,-1) -- (2.5,-1) -- (2.5,1) (6,0) -- (7,1) -- (8,1) -- (9,0) (6,0) -- (7,-1) -- (8,-1) -- (9,0);
\node at (0,1.25) {\(a\)};
\node at (0,-1.25) {\(a\)};
\node at (6.5,.75) {\(a\)};
\node at (7.5,1.25) {\(a\)};
\node at (2.25,0) {\(b\)};
\node at (3.5,1.25) {\(c\)};
\node at (4.75,0) {\(b\)};
\node at (3.5,-1.25) {\(c\)};
\node at (8.5,.75) {\(b\)};
\node at (8.5,-.75) {\(c\)};
\node at (7.5,-1.25) {\(b\)};
\node at (6.5,-.75) {\(c\)};
\node at (0,-2) {\(a^+a^+\)};
\node at (3.5,-2) {\(b^+c^-b^-c^+\)};
\node at (7.5,-2) {\(a^+a^+b^+c^+b^-c^-\)};
\node at (1.5,0) {\huge{\#}};
\node at (5.5,0) {\huge{$\cong$}};
\draw[dashed, -latex, shorten >= 3pt] (7,1) -- (7.75,-.5);
\draw[dashed] (7,1) -- (8,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  % style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
  on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
      }}},
}
\path [draw=blue,postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=red}}]
(1,-1) -- (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,1) -- (3,0) -- (2,-1) -- (1,-1) (5,-1) -- (4,0) -- (5,1) -- (6,1) -- (7,0) -- (6,-1) -- (5,-1);
\node at (1.5,-1.25) {\(b\)};
\node at (0.375,-0.625) {\(c\)};
\node at (0.375,.625) {\(d\)};
\node at (1.5,1.25) {\(c\)};
\node at (2.675,0.625) {\(b\)};
\node at (2.675,-.625) {\(d\)};

\node at (5.5,-1.25) {\(e\)};
\node at (4.375,-0.625) {\(e\)};
\node at (4.375,.625) {\(f\)};
\node at (5.5,1.25) {\(f\)};
\node at (6.675,0.625) {\(g\)};
\node at (6.675,-.625) {\(g\)};
\node at (3.5,0) {\huge{$\cong$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

My own is to create a simplified code in which, in a part (maybe the first...) I declare soon the `\tikzstyle` and another part (**separated by tikzset**). Is it possible. Thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to repeat the `\tikzset` command inside each picture. You can place one call to it in the preamble of your document, and all the pictures will be able to use it:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames, x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\tikzset{
  % style to apply some styles to each segment of a path
  on each segment/.style={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      show path construction,
      moveto code={},
      lineto code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      curveto code={
        \path [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)
        .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..
        (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
      closepath code={
        \path [#1]
        (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
      },
    },
  },
  % style to add an arrow in the middle of a path
  mid arrow/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[#1]{stealth}}
      }}},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [draw=blue,postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=red}}]
(.2,0) -- (3,1) arc (0:180:1.4 and 1) -- cycle
(4,1) circle(.8)
(6,1) ellipse(.5 and 1)
(0,3) to [bend left] (3,4)
(4,3) rectangle (6,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path [draw=blue,postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=red}}]
(0,0) rectangle (2,2) (0,2) -- (2,0) (7,0) -- (7,2) -- (9,0) -- (7,0) (8,2) -- (10,2) -- (10,0) (8,2) -- (10,0);
\node at (-.25,1) {\(a\)};
\node at (2.25,1) {\(a\)};
\node at (1,2.25) {\(u\)};
\node at (1,-.25) {\(v\)};
\node at (-1.5,1) {\Huge{\(P_{w'}=\)}};
\node at (4.5,1) {\huge{\(\xRightarrow[\text{la diagonale}]{\text{tagliando lungo}}\)}};
\node at (6.75,1) {\(a\)};
\node at (10.25,1) {\(a\)};
\node at (9,2.25) {\(u\)};
\node at (8,-.25) {\(v\)};
\node at (8,1.35) {\(b\)};
\node at (9,0.65) {\(b\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [draw=blue,postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=red}}]
(0,0) circle (1cm) (4.5,-1) -- (4.5,1) -- (2.5,1) (4.5,-1) -- (2.5,-1) -- (2.5,1) (6,0) -- (7,1) -- (8,1) -- (9,0) (6,0) -- (7,-1) -- (8,-1) -- (9,0);
\node at (0,1.25) {\(a\)};
\node at (0,-1.25) {\(a\)};
\node at (6.5,.75) {\(a\)};
\node at (7.5,1.25) {\(a\)};
\node at (2.25,0) {\(b\)};
\node at (3.5,1.25) {\(c\)};
\node at (4.75,0) {\(b\)};
\node at (3.5,-1.25) {\(c\)};
\node at (8.5,.75) {\(b\)};
\node at (8.5,-.75) {\(c\)};
\node at (7.5,-1.25) {\(b\)};
\node at (6.5,-.75) {\(c\)};
\node at (0,-2) {\(a^+a^+\)};
\node at (3.5,-2) {\(b^+c^-b^-c^+\)};
\node at (7.5,-2) {\(a^+a^+b^+c^+b^-c^-\)};
\node at (1.5,0) {\huge{\#}};
\node at (5.5,0) {\huge{$\cong$}};
\draw[dashed, -latex, shorten >= 3pt] (7,1) -- (7.75,-.5);
\draw[dashed] (7,1) -- (8,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [draw=blue,postaction={on each segment={mid arrow=red}}]
(1,-1) -- (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,1) -- (3,0) -- (2,-1) -- (1,-1) (5,-1) -- (4,0) -- (5,1) -- (6,1) -- (7,0) -- (6,-1) -- (5,-1);
\node at (1.5,-1.25) {\(b\)};
\node at (0.375,-0.625) {\(c\)};
\node at (0.375,.625) {\(d\)};
\node at (1.5,1.25) {\(c\)};
\node at (2.675,0.625) {\(b\)};
\node at (2.675,-.625) {\(d\)};

\node at (5.5,-1.25) {\(e\)};
\node at (4.375,-0.625) {\(e\)};
\node at (4.375,.625) {\(f\)};
\node at (5.5,1.25) {\(f\)};
\node at (6.675,0.625) {\(g\)};
\node at (6.675,-.625) {\(g\)};
\node at (3.5,0) {\huge{$\cong$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```